# How to create Arabic Sign Language Keyboard in Android?

Tags: keyboard, arabic, sign

Is there any way to get started with Arabic Sign Langauge Keyboard in Android. Is there anything available or I have to create something new from scratch.

Once I create my own, from the individual symbols, how can I connect this with Arabic language? How can I search the given sign word from the Sign Language Dictionary?

Any info is highly appreciable.

Regards
Symadept

Comment: Do you mean making a keyboard for the use of the arabic dialect of  sign language? Or are you asking about a keyboard to write arabic letters with?

Answer (score 0):

there is no an standard Arabic sign language keyboard.
you should create it from scratch as I did.

please try the app and do not hesitate to ask me any question about the implementation

my app is used to convert the Arabic sign language to Arabic speech.
here is the link for the app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.fampennings.keyboard

and this link will help you to construct your awn keyboard
http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm